# What does condition $L^p$ on a distribution mean?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am reading a [paper](https://cowles.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/pub/d06/d0664.pdf) and one of the conditions of a theorem on a random variable $x$ is $x \in L^p$, where $p > 0$. What does $L^p$ mean?

The paper does not define this notation anywhere, so I think the notation must be well-known. It makes the following remark that might be useful to find out what $L^p$ means: Distributions such as normal, uniform, exponential, logistic, Laplace, $t$, $\mathcal{X}^2$, Weibull with $c\geq 1$ and Cauchy (which is $L^p$ for $0<p<1$) satisfy the theorem conditions. So I'm assuming that these distributions are $L^p$.

Comment: $X$ is a random variable such that $\mathbb E[|X|^p] < \infty$.  Then we say $X$ belongs to $L^p$.

Comment: Google: "Lp space random variables" for more.